# Counting the same Strings in List

Tags: java, list

I am new to Android and Java programming. I have a problem with this method.
I am trying to count how many times the same strings appeared.

For example: input in list `l`, output in list `m`

List `l`:

- string1
- string1
- string2
- string2
- string2

List `m`:

- 2x string1
- 3x string2

My lists:

```
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> m = new ArrayList<>();
```

My method:

```
public String Generuj() {
    String generator = "";
    int x = 0;
    int j = 0;


    if (l.size() > 0) {
        m.add(l.get(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < l.size(); i++) {
            while (j < l.size() && m.get(m.size() - 1).equals(l.get(j))) {
                x++;
                j++;
            }
            m.add("\n" + x + "x " + l.get(i));
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        generator = generator.concat(m.get(i));
    }
    return generator;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: you can use a HashMap to keep a count of the strings' occurrences like in this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363665/hashmap-implementation-to-count-the-occurences-of-each-character

Comment: What should be result if list 1 contains `a, a, b, b, b, a`? Should it be `2x a, 3x b, 1x a` or maybe `3x a, 3x b`?

Comment: Why is there `m.add(l.get(0))`?

Comment: And your problem is what exactly?

Comment: The topic is covered in Documentation section: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams/909/creating-a-frequency-map#t=201607261747065850709

Answer (score 2):

Modified OP's solution: (Without `HashMap`)

```
public String Generuj() {
    String generator = "";
    int x = 0;

    while(l.size() > 0) {
        String someString=l.remove(0);
        x=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < l.size();) {
            if(l.get(i).equals(someString)){
                x++;
                l.remove(i);
            }else{
                i++;
            }
        }
        m.add("\n" + x + "x " + someString);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        generator = generator.concat(m.get(i));
    }
    return generator;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As wanpanman as say you can use hashmap :

```
 private void countEachString(List<String> strings) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> stringCountMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (String string : strings) {
            if (!stringCountMap.containsKey(string)) stringCountMap.put(string, 0);
            stringCountMap.put(string, stringCountMap.get(string) + 1);
        }
        print(stringCountMap);
    }

    private void print(HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap) {
        for (String string : hashMap.keySet()) {
            Log.d("print out", hashMap.get(string) + " x " + string);
        }
    }
```

you can change the print for whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `HashMap< String, Integer >` rather than simply prepending an `x`. By doing something like this:

```
HashMap< String, Integer > countMap = new HashMap<>();
for( String s : l )
{
   if( countMap.containsKey( s ) )
   {
      // Add one to the string's occurrence.
      countMap.put( s, countMap.get( s ) + 1 );
   }
   else
   {
      // Set the string's first occurrence.
      countMap.put( s, 1 );
   }
}
```

You have the count of all the occurrences of all the strings in the input list.  If you still need to print out the results, you can iterate through that `HashMap`'s `EntrySet` and concatenate from there:

```
generator.concat( entry.getValue() + "x " + entry.getKey() );
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can easily do it with streams:

```
List<String> result = l.stream() // stream list l
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy( // collect list elements to map grouping by keys and counting values
            Function.identity(),
            Collectors.counting()
        )
    )
    .entrySet() // get map's entry set
    .stream() // and stream it
    .map(entry -> entry.getValue() + "x " + entry.getKey()) // map each map entry to result string
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect the results to new list
```