# Compress string method isn't returning a new string?

Tags: java, string, methods, compression

I'm trying to make a method that compresses a string. For example, the method would take "ttttesst" and return "4te2st."

When I run the method and print the result, I get: ""

```
public class Compress {

public static String compress(String original){
    int count = 1;
    int oglength = original.length()-1;
    StringBuilder newword = new StringBuilder("");
    for(int i = 0; i < oglength; i = i+count){
        count = 1;
        for(int k = 1; k < oglength-k-i; k++){
            if(original.charAt(i) == original.charAt(i+k)){
                count++;
                continue;
            } else if(original.charAt(i) != original.charAt(i+k) && original.indexOf(original.charAt(i+k)) - original.indexOf(original.charAt(i)) > 1){
                newword.append(newword);
                newword.append(count);
                newword.append(original.charAt(i));
                break;
            } else if(original.charAt(i) != original.charAt(i+k) && original.indexOf(original.charAt(i+k)) - original.indexOf(original.charAt(i)) == 1){
                newword.append(newword);
                newword.append(original.charAt(i));
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    String returnword = newword.toString();
    return returnword;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to print occurrence of char value? if yes,then output should be 2s5t1e as per your input.

Comment: the string is kept in the same order, and only consecutive strings of the same character will have a the number of occurrences of that character.

Answer (score 0):

Compress method appends nothing in case of repetition with misuse of increment indices.

Here is a working version based on your approach:

```
public static String compress(String original) {
    int count;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i = i + count) {
        count = 1;
        for (int k = i + 1; k < original.length(); k++) {
            if (original.charAt(i) == original.charAt(k)) {
                count++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (count > 1) {
            builder.append(count).append(original.charAt(i));
        } else {
            builder.append(original.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with your program as you are having `unnnecessary loops` that increases complexity and `if-else ladder` that compares characters that you can't keep track of in your mind (This is where `debugging` might help you).

I don't understand what use case you are trying to get through but if you want exactly what you have mentioned above then following code snippet does it for you.

`Note:` I have only taken basic scenarios in mind. For large number of test cases few small changes might be needed.

```
public class Demo {

public static String compress(String original){
    int count = 0;
    char temp = original.charAt(0);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    for(int i=0;i<original.length();i++) {

        if(original.charAt(i)==temp) {
            count++;
        }else {
            if(count!=1)
                sb.append(count).append(temp);
            else
                sb.append(temp);

            count=1;

            temp=original.charAt(i);
            continue;
        }

    }
    if(count!=1)
        sb.append(count).append(temp);
    else
        sb.append(temp);
    //Above four lines get last character 
    //and its occurrence if it's more than 1. 


    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(compress("ttttesst")); 
//Enter desired String value here.
//Also you may make it user-interactive.
}
}
```

Also you can refer to following links,
[Count number of  occurrence of characters](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-count-occurrences-character/) and [HashMap Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363665/hashmap-implementation-to-count-the-occurences-of-each-character) and [Hashing used for counting occurrence of character](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/hash-tables/basics-of-hash-tables/tutorial/) to get better understanding how to approach problems like this.

I hope this helps !